# Calculate Percentage SQL Oracle Using Subqueries

Tags: sql, oracle

My intention is get a percentage of people that have a positive (COMISSAO) but i get an error while using the Subquery on the MAIN SELECT (**`Select to_number(Count(*)) FROM EMPREGADO`**).

My ideia to calculate the percentage was to do:

(3 **[Number of people that have a positive Comissao]** * 100)/ 14 **[Total number of people]**

```
TABLE EMPREGADO:

NUMEMP|COMISSAO

7839|(Null)
7566|(Null)
7782|(Null)
7698|(Null)
7788|(Null)
7844|0
7900|(Null) 
7902|(Null)
7369|(Null) 
7499|   300
7521|   500
7654|   1400
7876|(Null) 
7934|(Null) 

SELECT (COUNT(NVL(EMP.COMISSAO,0))*100)/(Select to_number(Count(*)) FROM EMPREGADO)
    FROM  EMPREGADO EMP
    WHERE EMP.COMISSAO>0
```

The Expected output is: 21

Comment: `to_number(Count(*))` is totally useless. It first converts the result of `count(*)` (which is a number) to a string, just to convert that string back to a number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need is a well placed `CASE` statement:

```
select
  count(case when comissao > 0 then 1 else null end) * 100.0 / count(*)
from empergado
```

And here is a sample [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/f45a3/1) with how the query works.

Answer (score 2):

No need for a Scalar Subquery, simply do a conditional aggregate:

```
SELECT COUNT(NULLIF(EMP.COMISSAO,0))*100)/(Count(*)
FROM  EMPREGADO EMP
```